# Split a byte in a list of n bits

Tags: java, byte, bitwise-operators, bit

I have a byte and I have to divide it into blocks of `n` bits and put these sequences in a list.

Examples:

**if n=2:**

```
byte b = {171}_10 = {1010 1011}_2
 --> list = {10, 10, 10, 11}
```

**if n=2:**

```
byte b = {108}_10 = {0110 1100}_2
 --> list = {01, 10, 11, 00}
```

**if n=3:**

```
byte b = {171}_10 = {1010 1011}_2
 --> list = {101, 010} -> I removed the last 2 bits
```

**if n=3:**

```
byte b = {108}_10 = {0110 1100}_2
 --> list = {011, 011}  -> I removed the last 2 bits
```

How can I do this?

Comment: So what part are you stuck at? What have you tried so far? Can you show us some code?

Comment: Why do you remove las 2 bits?

Comment: I read the java guide about bitwise operators but this don't help me...

Comment: I remove last 2 bits because I'm trying to calculate the entropy of order n of a file. So the sequences of n bits are the patterns, and i don't care about them

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this:

```
int len=2;
int number=1212;
char[] chars = Integer.toString(number, 2).toCharArray();
String[] strs= new String[(chars.length+len-1)/len];
for(int i=0,j=0;i<chars.length;i+=len,j++)
{
   strs[j]=new String(Arrays.copyOfRange(chars,i,i+len));
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strs))
```

**len** variable indicates the length of the blocks (your n). Set your desired number to **number** variable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small example of how this could easily be accomplished.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer sizeOfChunks = 2;
    Integer convertThisToBytes = 1234;
    List<String> sequenceOfBitChunks = new ArrayList<String>();
    String binaryRepresentation = Integer.toBinaryString(convertThisToBytes);
    
    System.out.println(binaryRepresentation);
    
    for(int i = 0; i + sizeOfChunks <= binaryRepresentation.length(); i = i + sizeOfChunks){
        sequenceOfBitChunks.add(binaryRepresentation.substring(i, i + sizeOfChunks));
    }
    
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sequenceOfBitChunks.toArray()));
}
```

Output:

> 10011010010
>
> [10, 01, 10, 10, 01]

if `sizeOfChunks = 3` the output becomes

> 10011010010
>
> [100, 110, 100]